# Routing 2 subnets

Tags: networking, router, routing, home-networking, subnet

I have the following network topology as on the bellow picture.

[image: Network topology]

Briefly:

1. Router A is connected to the internet and has local IP of 192.168.1.1. It is also a DHCP and serves clients on LAN or WiFi.
2. Router B is connected directly via LAN (onboard switches) to Router A. It has IP of 192.168.1.2. It also serves clients too.

Now comes the tricky part. Router C connects to Router B as WiFi client (bridge) and has local static IP of 192.168.1.200. (I tried to connect it as WDS but I couldn't - probably because I don't know how to).

All Computers/WiFi devices connecting to either Router A, or B, or C they get their dynamic IPs from the DHCP of router A and their gateway is 192.168.1.1 independed of which router they connect to.

My problem is the following. I am trying to isolate all devices (computers and later WiFis) on Router C from the other devices on Routers A and B. As such I thought to create a new Lan with its own IP addresses (yellow background). As such, I have enabled the VLan1 functionality to all 4 ports of Router C. I assigned a VLAN interface IP for the router of 192.168.2.1 and I enabled also DHCPD on that VLan to give addresses on the 192.168.2 subnet.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Should all my routers (all 3) have a 255.255.0.0 subnet mask since I need 2 Lans (192.168.1.x & 192.168.2.x) or it isn't needed and all routers can have the 255.255.255.0 mask.
2. Assuming that I have 255.255.255.0 everywhere, I guess that I need to do some kind of routing (especially for the VLAN1) so that routers need to communicate.

I thought that if I add 2 static routes on my Router C (see values in pictures bellow) I will be able to solve my problem but whenever I try to ping from the router to a computer on the 192.168.2.x subnet or the router B at 192.168.1.2 I don't have a pong...

The routes that I added to the router C are the following 2:

```
Name      Metric Destination/Subnet         Gateway        Interface
From2To1     0   192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0  192.168.1.200    auth0
From1To2     0   192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0  192.168.2.1      vlan1
```

Maybe I did it wrong and I don't need at all any static route on Router C since it knows both subnets but I need only a static route on either router A (or B) that has destination Lan: 192.168.2.0 and gateway the IP of the Auth0 interface of router C (192.168.1.200)?

Any idea please?